# Spring boot server receiving param with %20 instead of space

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have spring boot server with controller and one endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/readProperty", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<ReferenceDataRestResponse> getReferenceDatav4
        (WebRequest request) {
    Map<String, String[]> parametersMap = new HashMap<>(request.getParameterMap());

    ....

}
```

And another spring boot application which is sending request with restTemplate.getForEntity

```
String url = UriComponentsBuilder
   .fromHttpUrl(this.referenceDataBaseUrl)
   .path(this.referenceDataReadProperty)
   .queryParams(new LinkedMultiValueMap(multiValueParams))
   .toUriString();
log.info("Reference data URL {}", url);
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = this.refDataRestTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
```

info log with url prints this:

> `Reference data URL http://some-name:8080/readProperty?channel=E&service_name=Some%20Value`

Problem is that when I call this endpoint with curl command and with restTemplate.getForEntity I receive different values for service_name param in controller

**1. Curl**

When I copy this url from log and call it with curl command like this:

> `curl 'http://some-name:8080/readProperty?channel=E&service_name=Some%20Value'`

My endpoint is receiving service_name param as

> Some Value

**2. Java call with restTemplate.getForEntity(...)**

When java is calling this url with:

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = this.refDataRestTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class, new Object[0]);
```

My endpoint is receiving service_name param as

> Some%20Value

**3. Question**

How should I prepare request using spring boot to receive in controller decoded param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an issue.

Url is encoded twice by java service. Once by toUriString(), second time by restTemplate.getForEntity

when I changed method which is sending request to:

```
String url = UriComponentsBuilder
   .fromHttpUrl(this.referenceDataBaseUrl)
   .path(this.referenceDataReadProperty)
   .queryParams(new LinkedMultiValueMap(multiValueParams))
   .toString();
log.info("Reference data URL {}", url);
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = this.refDataRestTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
```

Then it worked, parameter value have spaces instead of %20